# enum char decline c++

Tags: c++, enums

I'm trying to make a function that receives a character as a parameter and uses that to determine what colour I'll change the text to.
BTW this is a windows and "empty project".
So I thought I'd make a switch to select the right colour according to the input, but since one cannot use characters as cases in a switch I tried using an enum:

```
void setColour(char txt)
{
enum colour {R=1,G,B,T,H,N,O,Y,P,W};
colour text = txt;
....
}
```

But I got an error :"
A value "char" cannot be used to initialize an entity type "colour"
".

What happend and how can I do as described above?

Comment: "*one cannot use characters as cases in a switch*" - yes, you can.  `switch (txt) { case 'R': ... break; case 'T': ... break; ... }`  But, in your case, you can't assign a `char` to an enum *directly*, but you *can* typecast it, provided that the numeric value of the `char` matches one of the numeric values in the enum, eg: `colour text = static_cast<colour>(txt);`.

Comment: The colour `R` has the value 1 and the character `'R'` [has the value 82](http://www.asciitable.com/). How is the compiler supposed to make the connection?

Comment: @BoPersson: The compiler doesn't, you do: `colour text; switch (txt) { case 'R': text = colour::R; break; ... }` Obviously, you would have to define the `case` statements to use whatever numbering scheme the `char` actually uses on input

Comment: @Remy - Sure, my question was rather aimed at Eli.  :-)

Comment: @BoPersson: considering that I'm the one who mentioned `'R'`, not Eli, I would think your question was aimed at me.

Answer (score 2):

enums are integers, not characters. The R, G, B, T, etc. are just labels that represent the integers 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.

So when you go to set `text = txt`, you're trying to force a char into an integer variable.

You'll probably best sticking with characters and trying your switch statement again. Just make sure you wrap your characters in 'single quotes' so the compiler knows you mean a char.

```
void setColour(char txt)
{
    switch (txt)
    {
        case 'R':
            break;
        case 'T':
            break;
        default:
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be assignments in the cases?

Comment: There should be whatever the OP wants to do in the cases. I'm not sure what that is, but I don't think it's just an assignment. The function parameter is probably misleadingly named. It should be colour. I assume the text to be coloured is stored somewhere else.

Comment: I'd expect `case 'R': text = R; break;`

Comment: @HeathRaftery: "*enums are integers*" - not really. An enum has numeric values, but it is not itself an integer. If it were, assigning an integer to an enum without a typecast would be allowed, but it is not. "*you're trying to force a char into an integer variable*" - a `char` can be assigned to an `int` variable without a typecast, the language defines rules for that assignment. A `char`, or even an `int`, cannot be assigned to an `enum` variable without a typecast.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yep, all quite correct and good further reading for those that need it. I was trying to use language that would appeal to the OP. When I say "integer" I don't mean `int`.
@Barmar I believe `text` was only introduced when the OP tried to solve the problem with an enum instead of a switch. I don't actually think `text` is part of what the OP is trying to do, but that's up to them to explain I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler tries to say you that types `char` and `colours` are different types and char values can not be assigned to colours value. You can work around it using `static_cast`, but with little efforts. For example like below. This error is very useful because value ranges of numerics types are much wider than values of enums.

```
void setColour(char txt)
{
    enum colour: char {MIN, R=1,G,B,T,H,N,O,Y,P,W, MAX};
    colour text = R; // default colour
    if (MIN < txt && txt < MAX)
      text = static_cast<colour>(txt);
    ....
}
```

Since you use `char` as numeric type, it is better to use for example `uint8_t`. It will help to avoid misunderstands with 'R' char and R enum values.

Comment: This will get rid of the error, but it probably doesn't do what he wants. He's probably taking user input like `'R'` and wants that to assign `colour::R` to the variable.

Comment: @Barman You are right, but who knows what the author assumed. Maybe he chose the char as the minimum numeric type.

Answer (score 0):

The objects of enum data type is of integer type. So you can't assign a char to a int variable (but the reverse is possible).
 To solve your problem you can map your data type( like 1- red, 2- black......)
 or type cast your char variable to int variable.

```
void setColor(char txt)
 { enum colour {R=1,G,B,T,H,N,O,Y,P,W}; colour text =(int) txt; 
cout<<(char) txt;. // Assume text=b output b
....}
```

[For better understanding of enum](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/enumeration).

Your problem can be solved by using switch case.
[using chars in switch case](http://googleweblight.com/i?u=http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/6463/&hl=en-IN).
I just give suggestions to your problem and not the answers.